# Sending SMS to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, sms

I want to send an SMS to a specific list of people that updates every day. The list is the output of a SQL query and is stored in a data extension. I've looked at using an Import Definition in MobileConnect to transfer people from the DE into a mobileconnect list. The issue with this is that it only lets me add or update the list, not overwrite it.

Has anyone done something similar? Am I going about things in the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to do this without directly and no work arounds?, is just from my understanding is that this should be achievable but I am struggling to get this up and running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible word around is that you should import the Data extension into a mobile connect list mapping a field (status with values true/false) in order to update it.
Then you should create another list filtering by status, so that you could remove all the inactive contacts.